# Auto size the controls in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize

I've a winform and I placed a listbox in that form. When I maximize the winform the size of the list box remains same.

But I dont want like this. I want to adjust the size automatically.

Is there any default property for this?

Thank you,
Nagu

Answer (score 32):

Look for the anchor properties. You can set the anchor to resize automatically following the form.

The anchor has 4 sides. If you anchor to all 4 sides, the control will retain its size ratio according to the size of its parent form.

Answer (score 9):

Use the .Anchor property.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Dock Property of the listbox to fill. if you are using list box in some parent control like splitter panel