# Default windows forms resizing behavior

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resize

If I have created a forms app and not specified anything out of the ordinary (just used Visual Studio's designer to drag and drop controls), what behavior should I expect when resizing the window? Does it differ based on what controls I used? Is there detailed documentation of this someplace I can reference?

(I hate asking something so vague and contrived, but I don't have access to Visual Studio and the developers who do aren't being helpful. As far as I know they're using C# and not using any sort of layout panel.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to know about anchoring and docking the various components, how they hold together, and how they behave when resizing the form. Please see [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2231/Working-with-Anchoring-and-Docking-Properties) for a guide on how to do this effectively, and how some of the various options work.

Answer (score 1):

Controls on a WinForm application do not resize by default.  Look at using the Anchor property on controls.  For example.  If you want a button to widen when you widen a form go to the Anchor property on the button and anchor the left and right sides.  This will widen the button as the form widens.

You can think of the anchor as the parts that get "pulled" when a form moves.

See this post:
[Auto size the controls in winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623746/auto-size-the-controls-in-winform)

Comment: So they remain exactly in place by default, hidden when the window gets too small to show them, and any other behavior has been customized?