# C++ Scalable GUI window in visual studio for a complex form

Tags: c++, windows, forms, user-interface

I have been given the task of adding onto someone else's code. This person has developed a windows form in Visual Studio 2010 with a ton of controls, labels, tabs, images etc.

It works well, but the only problem is, they set the size of the window to be too large (they must have had a huge screen at home). Some of the controls are not accessible because it is too big. 
The window does not scale. 
I have scoured the internet, and tried various solutions, but to no avail.

Is there a way to group all of the previous work into a container and have it all scale when you scale the window?

Comment: Which version of C++ do you use? Which OS(I guess Win but it's still worth to ask)/Framework? In C++/CLI I would recommend a Table. In WPF you should use a Grid and Row/Column definitions.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to check. But I'm using Visual C++ Windows7

Comment: Do you see any #using or #include related to Qt, Windows, System or Forms?

Comment: #using <System.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
#using <System.Drawing.dll>

Comment: Ah, Winforms in C++/CLI. I recommend to look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623746/auto-size-the-controls-in-winform

Answer (score 0):

If you anchor the controls to the various sides of the container they will move as you scale the container.  So, for example, if you anchor a button to the right and bottom and then shrink the window from the bottom right the button will still be visible.  If you are using visual studio you can do this by either setting the preferences of the control or by dragging it close to the side of the container and having it "snap" to those sides.  It can also be done programatically although I am not 100% what the code is off the top of my head.

Comment: The only problem is, It doesn't actually "scale". When you size the window the features move according to the window, but they don't actually change size. If the window is too small, the elements just end up overlapping

Comment: I see your problem.  Honestly the only thing I can think of is adding a 'container resize' event to the controls and then programmatically changing their size based on the container size.  But if there are a lot of controls this could  be kind of a nightmare.